# Difficulty sending e-mail using python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to get Python to send e-mails. First, I started python smptd as follows:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Then, adapting the example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm, I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['brt381@gmail.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <brt381@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost:1025')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

When I run this script, I get the message "Successfully sent email". In my other terminal window (the one containing the python smptd), it shows this after running the script:

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <brt381@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test
X-Peer: ::1

This is a test e-mail message.
------------ END MESSAGE ------------
```

But... no e-mail gets sent. Any idea what might be wrong? This works just fine - the e-mail gets sent:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail brt381@gmail.com <<<"hello"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually sending (in the first example) your email through a local development smtp server, because you mention the `DebuggingServer` class which, as the [documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html#debuggingserver-objects) says :

> Create a new debugging server. Arguments are as per SMTPServer. 
>   **Messages will be discarded, and printed on stdout.**

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! Every single example of this I found on the internet mentioned the DebuggingServer argument and none of them happened to mention that this discards the message!